# Is a reflection a picture or an image?

Tags: word-usage, nouns

The reflection of your face (or anything else) in water or a mirror:

is that called a *picture* or an *image*?

Answer (score 2):

I would use **image**. We do use the phrase

> a mirror image

**Picture** has an implication of it being an artefact, something made. I would not say

> a mirror picture

We could also just say

> I can see my face in the mirror.

or

> I can see my reflection in the mirror.